# Providing a Default Value if no checkboxes are selected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

So I'm getting an error anytime I try to submit my form when I do not select a checkbox option. I've tried using an else statement underneath but when I do that, if I select a checkbox option or not it enters only the else statement.
I removed the else statement since it hasn't worked but what I had was:

```
  if (checkItem.Selected)
  { //build string
    valueFormat3 = string.Concat("#", checkItem.Value, ";");
    finalString3 += valueFormat3;
  } 
  else
   {
       finalString3 = ("#nothing selected#");
   }
```

**Error I get without the else statement:**

```
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex]
   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) +12995315
   EventFormWeb.Default.submit(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1364
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9815014
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

**C#:**

```
        string valueFormat3 = string.Empty;
        string finalString3 = string.Empty;

        //Get values of checklist items
        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem checkItem in tSChoices.Items)
        {
            if (checkItem.Selected)
            { //build string
                valueFormat3 = string.Concat("#", checkItem.Value, ";");
                finalString3 += valueFormat3;
            } 
        }
        //trim final string of leading and ending characters
        finalString3 = finalString3.Substring(1, finalString3.Length - 2);

        //pass choices as string, name sp name
        entry["tSChoices"] = finalString3;

        entry.Update(); // local item changes
        clientContext.Load(entry);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
    }
```

**HTML/ASP.NET:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    Technical Services
      <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" id="technicalServices" runat="server" onchange="dropthree.showHideInput(this, 'Yes')">
         <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="dropthree" runat="server" style="display:none;">
     <div class="row well well-sm">
        <div class="col-xs-12 checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="tSChoices" CssClass="styled" RepeatColumns="2" Type="checkbox" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Mic" Value="Mic" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Vid. Conference" Value="Video Conference" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Audio" Value="Audio" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Streaming" Value="Streaming" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="WiFi-Guest" Value="Wifi-Guest-Network" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Projector" Value="Projector" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Payment-Portal" Value="Payment Portal" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Laptop" Value="Laptop" />
          </asp:CheckBoxList>
      </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would imagine that is because finalString is empty, so its Length is (0 - 2) which is less than 1 which is what you have as your start index in your call to Substring()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you where your exception is coming from:

```
 //trim final string of leading and ending characters
     finalString3 = finalString3.Substring(1, finalString3.Length - 2);

   //So what happens in this call above if finalString3 is still empty????
   //Then you are making a call to .Substring() with start index of 1 and
   //has Length of 0 - 2 which equals -2
   //You can't have a string with a length of a negative number, plus
   //strings are basically character arrays and are zero indexed
   //So if you want to start at the first character you use zero
```

To answer the portion of the question which should resolve the exception change your line of code to this:

```
 //trim final string of leading and ending characters
   finalString3 = finalString3.Length < 3 ? "#nothing selected#" : finalString3.Substring(1, 
   finalString3.Length - 2);
```

Comment: @J.Lopez No problem, if you are happy with my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the C# code as below:

```
string valueFormat3 = string.Empty;
string finalString3 = string.Empty;

//Get values of checklist items
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem checkItem in tSChoices.Items)
{
    if (checkItem.Selected)
    { //build string
        valueFormat3 = string.Concat("#", checkItem.Value, ";");
        finalString3 += valueFormat3;
    }
}          
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(finalString3))
{
    //trim final string of leading and ending characters
    finalString3 = finalString3.Substring(1, finalString3.Length - 2);
}
```